# natural induced split exact sequence from $ 0\to \Bbb Z\xrightarrow{p}\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z_p\to 0$

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

> Multiplication by the prime $p:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$ fits in a short exact sequence
> $$ 0\to \Bbb Z\xrightarrow{p}\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z_p\to 0$$
> Use this to derive the natural split exact sequence
> $$0\to H_n(X)/pH_n(X)\to H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)\to\text{ker}\{p:H_{n-1}(X)\to H_{n-1}(X)\}\to 0$$

This is exercise 4.5.1 of Bredon's topology and geometry textbook. $0\to \Bbb Z\xrightarrow{p}\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z_p\to 0$ induces $0\to \Delta_{*}(X)\otimes\Bbb Z\to \Delta_{*}(X)\otimes\Bbb Z\to\Delta_*(X)\otimes \Bbb Z_p\to 0$ so a long exact sequence $\cdots\to H_n(X)\to H_n(X)\to H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)\to H_{n-1}(X)\to H_{n-1}(X)\to\cdots$. Then by first isomorphism theorem, $H_n(X)/pH_n(X)\simeq H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)$. Hence, it suffices to show $H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)\to H_{n-1}(X)$ is injective. How can I?

Edit: My naive approach is that if $\partial_*$ be a connecting homomorphism between $H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)$ and $H_{n-1}(X)$ and let $\Delta_{*}(X)\otimes\Bbb Z\xrightarrow{i} \Delta_{*}(X)\otimes\Bbb Z\xrightarrow{j}\Delta_*(X)\otimes \Bbb Z_p$ so that $H_n(X)\xrightarrow{i_*}H_n(X)\xrightarrow{j_*} H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)$, then for $[[c]]\in H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)$, if $\partial_*([[c]]) = [[i^{-1}\circ (\partial\otimes 1)\circ j^{-1}(c)]] = 0 \iff c=0$ as $i$ maps $\Bbb Z\to p\Bbb Z$. Is this valid?

Answer (score 1):

The point is that your long exact sequence actually takes the form

$\cdots\to H_n(X)\xrightarrow{p} H_n(X)\to H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)\to H_{n-1}(X)\xrightarrow{p} H_{n-1}(X)\to\cdots$

So $H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)$ surjects onto its image in $H_{n-1}(X)$, which by exactness is equal to the displayed kernel.

The first isomorphism theorem does not give $H_n(X)/pH_n(X) \cong H_n(X; \Bbb Z_p)$, but rather $H_n(X)/pH_n(X) \cong \operatorname{im}(H_n(X) \to H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p))$, and this image of course injects into $H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)$ and is also the kernel of the map from $H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)$ to $H_{n-1}(X)$.

Comment: Then how can I show the sequence splits? @kamills

Comment: Note that the short exact sequence is actually a short exact sequence of $\Bbb Z_p$-modules (each of the 3 terms in the sequence are all $p$-torsion). But $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field, and every short exact sequence in the category of $\Bbb Z_p$-modules splits.

Comment: I didn't learn about category theory so I was thinking the inverse map $H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p)\to H_n(X)/pH_n(X)$ by just inclusion onto $H_n(X)$ then projection to $H_n(X)/pH_n(X)$.

Comment: You can certainly try to construct a map and use the splitting lemma. But what is the inclusion $H_n(X;\Bbb Z_p) \to H_n(X;\Bbb Z)$?

Comment: Hmm... it seems I can't just take an inclusion map (I just thought about coefficient) right?

Comment: That's correct. There is only one homomorphism $\Bbb Z_p \to \Bbb Z$, the zero homomorphism. In general, it's not always possible to construct integral lifts of homology classes (by this long exact sequence it's possible for a class $x$ iff $\partial x = 0$), so you may have difficulty writing a left-splitting. I'd try writing down a right split (although I struggled with that for a bit and gave up). The "category theory" statement I wrote above boils down to the fact that a $\Bbb Z_p$-module is the same thing as a vector space over $\Bbb Z_p$, and short exact sequences of vector spaces split.

Comment: Ok, maybe writing down left or right inverse would be a bad move. You're saying $\text{ker}\{p:H_{n-1}(X)\to H_{n-1}(X)\}$ is free abelian so the sequence splits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117866/discussion-between-kamills-and-love-sodam).